# Copy vector of shared_ptr to derived classes of abstract base

Tags: c++

I'm trying to copy the object instances of derived classes from a `vector<shared_ptr<base>>` to a new `vector<shared_ptr<base>>` where the base class is abstract. I want the new `vector` to contain `shared_ptr` to copies of the objects, not the original objects.

I've tried this:

```cpp
class base
{
public:
    base(){}
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class derived1 : public base
{
public:
    derived1() : base() { };
    void method() {};
};

class derived2 : public base
{
public:
    derived2() : base() { };
    void method() {};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base>> vector1 =
    {
        std::make_shared<derived1>(),
        std::make_shared<derived2>()
    };

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base>> vector2;
    vector2.reserve(vector1.size());
    for (const auto& e : vector1)
    {
        vector2.push_back(std::make_shared<base>(*e));
    }
}
```

This is not working, since I'm not able to instantiate the base class. How can I do this properly?

Comment: You can add into your classes hierarchy a `clone` virtual member function that will return `std::shared_ptr<base>` which points to the copy of `*this`. It seems that this solution may be also automated by CRTP, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46916243/580083) (there is also a link to a relevant blogpost).

Comment: I doubt you really want to do that.

Comment: thnx, it was that simple ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to make a pure virtual clone method on the base class which returns a pointer - subclasses override this to allocate a copy of themselves.

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<base> clone() const = 0;
};

class derived1 : public base
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<base> clone() const override
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<base>(new derived1(*this));
    }
};
```